# Wordpress multiple loops and code duplicate

Tags: php, variable-assignment, wordpress

i'm building site on wordpress engine, and I need to display four loops on one page (every one from a different category).
I try to write it smart, cause I don't want code to duplicate.
Look at this:

http://codepad.org/aTh87QAN

As you can see, i don't' want to duplicate code that is in every loop, i mean lines 19-31.

```
<?php
    $events_sep = new WP_Query( array_merge($args_common, $args_sep) );
    while ($events_sep->have_posts()) : $events_sep->the_post();
?>
    <li class="event-entry date-<?php the_field('event-date'); ?>">
        <a href="index.php/<?php the_field('event-venue'); ?>">
            <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/img/program/<?php the_field('event-venue'); ?>-22px.jpg" alt="">
        </a>
        <?php echo the_content(); ?>
        <a class="permalink" href="index.php/<?php the_field('event-venue'); ?>">więcej informacji</a>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </li>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

So i tried saving it as a php variable, but It doesn't worked. I'm not very experienced with php (not as good as javascript), but I can't look at this code, probably you know what I mean ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's one of the things functions are for, doing repetitive tasks. Build one like this in your `functions.php` file:

```
function my_query_events( $common, $unique, $title, $class )
{
    echo "<h4>$title</h4>";
    echo "<ul class='events-list $class'>";
    $events_sep = new WP_Query( array_merge( $common, $unique ) );
    while ( $events_sep->have_posts() ) : $events_sep->the_post();
    ?>
    <li class="event-entry date-<?php the_field('event-date'); ?>">
        <a href="index.php/<?php the_field('event-venue'); ?>">
            <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/img/program/<?php the_field('event-venue'); ?>-22px.jpg" alt="">
        </a>
        <?php echo the_content(); ?>
        <a class="permalink" href="index.php/<?php the_field('event-venue'); ?>">więcej informacji</a>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </li>
    </ul>
    <?php 
    endwhile; 
}
```

And in your template call it a number of times passing your own specific arguments:

```
<ul class="program-info">
    <li class="pure-u-1-4 program-table">
        <?php my_query_events( $args_common, $args_sep, 'wrzesień', 'sep' ); ?>
        <?php my_query_events( $args_common, $args_oct, 'październik', 'oct' ); ?>
```

This example is untested, but gives you an idea on how to proceed and adapt to your needs.